# photo recovery tool for lost partition

Tags: data-recovery

is there a photo recovery tool for lost partition except photorec becuz photorec recovers all file extensions, I really need to recover photos, please don't tell me to use testdisk, I just need photo recovery tool.

Comment: Also related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/31450/tool-for-recovering-deleted-data-from-a-flash-drive  and https://askubuntu.com/questions/147367/recover-data-from-a-fat32-hard-disk - there are some alternatives.

Comment: Actually, photorec will recover whatever file extension you tell it to. If you only want jpg and png, you can tell photorec (testdisk) to only recover and search for jpg and png files.

Comment: @karel Thank's, I was just trying to let the OP know that so maybe they will give your answer a try. Also, I thought that I might get some clarification from the OP about that.

Comment: @karel this what happens when I use testdisk - https://pastebin.com/p0CYJrtv

Comment: Can you get hold of a bigger external hard drive? (>=500GB) Or alternatively and cheaper a USB external hard drive enclosure in case you have an extra unused hard drive that you can temporarily insert into the external hard drive enclosure.

Comment: i have external drive 1tb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With photorec before you start `[Search]` under `[File Opt]` you can choose the file extensions you wanna recover.

`photorec` is a part of `testdisk` project but `photorec` is for recoverying  files while `testdisk` is for recovering and repairing partitions.

Comment: Oh thanks I never saw it in my life you save my ass.

Comment: I have another problem, the recovered photos resolution was messed up please help me to recover the original files :(

Comment: @Glenn What do you mean messed up? If there was an error message, please post it.

Comment: The resolution of image I mean size become thumbnail size

Comment: @Glenn: it will of course also recover all thumbnails in addition to the originals. You should get those from sorting according to file size. All other images may be easier to recover when renamed (e.g. [according to EXIF data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346011/how-to-rename-multiple-photos-and-videos-based-on-exif-data))

Comment: Thank You everyone for all the answers all answers are useful now I will just need to wait until recovering files is done I'm currently booting from usb flash drive to prevent overwritting my lost files.

Comment: This answer recovered my engagement photos that were lost on an SD card due to water from a waterfall. THANK YOU. Invaluable

Comment: @Jonathan, It made me happy, I wish you both the happiest memories.